# Move Project From Root Solution Folder to Subfolder in Visual Studio

Tags: git, azure-devops, visual-studio-2019, .net-4.8, multiple-projects

I have a .NET Framework (4.8) C# Class Library project in Visual Studio 2019. The solution is structured as follows:

```
-- Root Folder
    -- .git
    -- .vs
    -- *.cs
    -- bin
    -- Project.sln
    -- Project.csproj
```

I have the solution in a remote Azure DevOps (git) repository. The solution is also referencing another project in a different folder. I want to have these projects in the same solution so that they will both push changes to my remote repository. I want the structure to be as follows:

```
-- Root Folder
    -- .git
    -- .vs
    -- Project.sln
    -- Project 1 Folder
        -- .vs
        -- *.cs
        -- bin
        -- Project1.csproj
    -- Project 2 Folder
        -- .vs
        -- *.cs
        -- bin
        -- Project2.csproj
```

I don't want to have to create a new solution because I will then have to create a new remote repository, and I already have multiple past branches that I use for reference. I've already tried to move the projects into folders manually, but the folders did not appear in the solution explorer even though I selected to show all files. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the relationship between the solution and the remote repository. That being said, it may not matter...

**First re-org your projects:** once you've moved your projects into the folder structure you want, from within Visual Studio, remove the project(s) from your solution, and then re-add them from their new locations. Note using VS for this is probably easier than trying to manually update all the paths in the .sln file.

**Now update your source code in Git:** After you're happy with the result, all the files you moved will appear as modified and/or renamed (or possibly added and deleted). Stage all the changes you want to keep and then commit.

**Tip for Git beginners:** if you aren't entirely sure what you're doing or you're new to Git, if you are ever in a position where you'd cry if you lost your work, make a copy of it *outside of your Git repo* for sanity purposes; you can always delete it later once you're sure you have your code properly committed.